# How to avoid duplicating a property in a nested class structure?

Tags: oop

For example, I have the following class structure:

```
Animal
---Cat
------property: CatCollar (boolean)
---Dog
------BigDog
------TinyDog
---------property: CatCollar (boolean)
```

I have the same property CatCollar in class Cat and in class TinyDog, but this property should not be in the class BigDog. My reviewer tells me that this is a bad structure, as it leads to duplication. I cannot change the structure of classes, but I can only change this property (location and other manipulation). Maybe there are some OOP tools that allow you to do this? Can I somehow avoid duplicating a property? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object-orientation it doesn't matter what "data" (i.e. private state) each object has. It only matters what *behavior* they provide, even in an inheritance tree.

So, if by "property" you mean a public state, or a private state accessible through a public getter, you already left object-orientation to a certain degree. Discussing what is right from the perspective of oop is already moot.

If you mean that as a private state, with some potential behavior shared, then you might need *delegation*. That is, both `Cat` and `TinyDog` implementing some interface describing the desired behavior, then implementing it in some class that both delegate to (i.e. contain). Unfortunately this is not natively supported in Java (in Kotlin for example it is), so it needs some boilerplate.